# Content Script not working as expected in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm making a chrome extension for personal use that essentially unhides your grade on canvas. I have the manifest v3 and the content script set up, however, the content script logs an empty object when I try to console.log my object. Note: The code isn't complete yet, I'm just testing what I have so far.

I tried to console.log an object I have that contains each assignment group and the respective grade within that group. However the console shows an empty object or nothing at all.

Heres the manifest:

```
{
"name": "Grade Revealer",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "A cool extension",
"permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
"manifest_version": 3,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://instructure.com/courses/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
]
```

}

And heres the content script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
let items = document.querySelector("#assigments")
let assGrpGrades = {}

if(items){
    items.querySelectorAll(".student_assignment").forEach((item) => {
        let possiblePoints = parseFloat(item.querySelector(".points_possible").innerText)
        console.log(possiblePoints)
        let pointsScored = parseFloat(item.querySelector(".grade").innerText)
        let group = item.querySelector(".context").innerText
        if(!assGrpGrades.hasOwnProperty(group)){
            assGrpGrades[group] = 0
            assGrpGrades[group + "PossiblePoints"] = 0
        }
        assGrpGrades[group] += pointsScored
        assGrpGrades[group + "PossiblePoints"] += possiblePoints
    })
}

for(let group in Object.keys(assGrpGrades)){
    assGrpGrades[group] = assGrpGrades[group]/assGrpGrades[group + "PossiblePoints"]
}

console.log(assGrpGrades)
```

});

I tried both with and without the DOMContentLoaded event. Thanks for any help.

Edit: Heres version 2 of the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
let items = document.querySelectorAll("#assigments .student_assignment")
let assGrpGrades = {}

if(items){
    items.forEach((item) => {
        let possiblePoints = parseFloat(item.querySelector(".points_possible").innerText)
        let pointsScored = parseFloat(item.querySelector(".grade").innerText)
        let group = item.querySelector(".context").innerText
        if(!assGrpGrades.hasOwnProperty(group)){
            assGrpGrades[group] = {
                pointsScored: 0,
                possiblePoints: 0
            }
        }
        assGrpGrades[group].pointsScored += pointsScored
        assGrpGrades[group].possiblePoints += possiblePoints
    })
}

for(let group in assGrpGrades){
    let totalPointsScored = assGrpGrades[group].pointsScored
    let totalPossiblePoints = assGrpGrades[group].possiblePoints
    assGrpGrades[group].averageScore = totalPointsScored / totalPossiblePoints
}

console.log(assGrpGrades)
```

});

Please let me know if this is better or worse

Comment: I *highly* doubt that exception is raised as a result of your code. What you're probably seeing is simply the console of the actual website. Does the "Dom fully loaded" show? Try changing some element's text to "XXXXX", does that happen? Start small. Even smaller than what you have now

Comment: @Yarin_007 thanks for the reply. To your point, the dom fully loaded log doesn't show. Would it be possible to elaborate on the "XXXXX" thing? Thank you. Edit: By the way, I just realized that you are right, that error isn't coming from my code.

Comment: @Yarin_007 sorry for the second reply, but I removed the dom content loaded event and the code is logging things again, however it's back to printing the empty object.

Comment: Check console.log for the value of each variable, eg items.

Comment: Modern sites generate the page in JS after DOMContentLoaded so your code runs too early and won't see the generated elements. Use MutationObserver instead.

Comment: Remove the blanks in "#asigments .student_assignment".